# I am having a combobox in flash, it works for one time only

Tags: flash, combobox

I am having a standard comboBox in flash AS2
When I select the first item in it, I execute the following code

```
loadMovie("Tr_Lessons/Tr_Lessons_L01/Tr_Lessons_L01S02/Viewer.swf",0);
```

and so on when I select other items

The problem is that the combobox works only for the first time and when the new file is loaded, the combobox hangs and doesn't be opened to view the listed items

Any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the loaded movie ovelaps the combobox and is catching all mouse events. You'd need to create an emtpy movieClip, place it on a lower layer than your combobox and load the movies into that empty movieclip, like

```
myEmptyMC.loadMovie("...");
```

Comment: We are loading totally different swf with the same combobox, it works in the first call but in other calls the combo is not opened to select from it